# Map has 2 of the same keys

Tags: apex, map, loop

I retrieved a list of records that have a lookup to a parent record with a unique id.

Parent record --<Child Records.

I have a map that has two of the same key in it. I'm not sure how to understand the Map<Id, sObject> relationship when casting from a list.

```
List<ChildRecords__c> childRecordsList = new List<ChildRecords__c>();    
Map<Id, ChildRecords__c> caseChildMap = new Map<Id, ChildRecords__c>(childRecordList);
            for (Id key : caseChildMap.keySet()) {
                System.debug(key);  
            }
```

The parent record that is triggering this has two childrecords in it. And loops through 2 times showing that the Id (key) twice. My understanding was that a map can only have one unique key that unlocks the value it's associated it with.

Anyone know what is going on here?

When I run it like this. I get two unique ids from the childrecords that are associated with the ID. I'm aware that what is happening is that that the Id seems to be associated with a list of child records and iterating over them, however, I'm not sure how the mechanism works and looking for more detail on the logic of how the map functions in this way.

```
 List<ChildRecords__c> childRecordsList = new List<ChildRecords__c>();    
    Map<Id, ChildRecords__c> caseChildMap = new Map<Id, ChildRecords__c>(childRecordList);
                for (Id key : caseChildMap.keySet()) {
                   System.debug(caseChildMap.get(key).Id);  
                }
```

Comment: Without seeing the debug output, it's hard to validate what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The `Map<Id, sObject> var = new Map<Id, sObject>(listOfsObject);` (where sObject is any type of object, like Account or CustomObject__c) is semantically equal to:

```
Map<Id, sObject> var = new Map<Id, sObject>();
for(sObject record: listOfsObject) {
  var.put(record.Id, record);
}
```

Note that you're not *casting* (explicit conversion from one type to another), you're using a constructor with a parameter to initialize a new object. It's important to get this sort of terminology correct so you don't confuse yourself later.

You haven't explained the code surrounding this method/code you're calling, but you definitely can *not* have two identical keys in this case, because the constructor will throw a System.ListException if you try:

```
Account[] a = [select id from account limit 1];
a.addAll(a);
System.debug(new Map<Id, Account>(a));
// Line: 3, Column: 1
// System.ListException: Row with duplicate Id at index: 1
```

Assuming you're calling one loop immediately after the other, you're outputting the key, followed by the record's Id, which is the same value (so, you'd see two debug statements).

Just know that this construct is automatically initializing the map with the list of records, organized by their unique record Id.